# JavaScript:Set default values ​for an object

Tags: javascript, json

Hello i'm trying to find a way to set defined values ​​in a separate file to populate my function:

my function index.js:

```
const Modes = (array) => {
  return {
    name: array.name,
    funcionarioIncrease: array.funcionarioValor,
    socioIncrease: array.socioValue,
    faturamento: array.faturamento
  }
}
```

my schema.json

```
    {   
  "name": "SIMPLES NACIONAL – MEI",   "funcionarioIncrease": 49.99,  
  "socioIncrease": 0,
  "FATURAMENTO": [
        {
          "name": "ATÉ 30.000,00",
          "value": 149.99
        },
        {
          "name": "De 30.001,00 a 50.000,00 ",
          "value": 199.90
        }   ] 
}
```

but i'm not sure how to do this and if .json is the correct way

Comment: What do you mean by default value?

Comment: why you need to store it in json, is it static file which gets modified or changed regularly if not can be stored as simple constants file and import / require it?

Comment: yes it can be like .js, I need an array of this object

Answer (score 0):

You can use a JS file full of constant values and import it.

For example:

**costants.js**

```
export const NAME="MyTestName";
export const SOCIO_INCREASE=0;
export const FATURAMENTO=[{id:1}]
```

and in you functional component:

**functional.js**

```
import {NAME,SOCIO_INCREASE,FATURAMENTO} from "./constants.js"

const Modes = ({
    name=NAME,
    socioIncrease=SOCIO_INCREASE,
    faturamento=FATURAMENTO
}) => {
  return {
    name,
    socioIncrease,
    faturamento
  }
}
```

Remember that if you pass some of this props to your functional component, the default values will be overwrited.